# Is this predicate logic semantic tree open or closed?

Tags: predicate-logic

I have this formula: $\forall y\neg A(y)\land\exists x A(x)$ .

Is a semantic tree for this formula closed or open?

Comment: The formula is obviously *unsatisfiable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it is closed.

Just think about the definition of closed formula :

A formula is closed if it does not contains free occurrence.

Comment: IMO, the question is about the [semantic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux#Propositional_logic) and not about the syntax of the formula.